# mySQL: Selecting rows or default values joining other tables

Tags: mysql

I need to select records depending on different params – and if a record is missing, then a default value.

Here are the tables

```
absence_type
+------+--------+
|id    | value  |
+------+--------+
|1     |  null  |
|2     |  null  |
|3     |  20    |
|4     |  null  |
|5     |  null  |
|6     |  null  |
|7     |  null  |
|8     |  null  |
|9     |  null  |
+------+--------+

absences
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|id     | absenceType | employeeId  | totalDuration  | startDate  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|145    |  9          |    112      |   1            | 2023-01-13 |
|146    |  5          |    406      |   1            | 2023-11-15 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------+

absence_balance
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
|id     | absenceType | employeeId  | entitlement    | periodYear  | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
|13     |  1          |    112      |   10           |    2022     |
|53     |  1          |    112      |   12           |    2023     |
|54     |  2          |    406      |   5            |    2023     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

The request will have an employee id, period year and a set of type ids, which are allowed, say '1,2,3,4,9'.

At the end I need to have all types with absences within that periodYear and if a particular type is missing in absences OR balances, I still have to display a default value for that type (absence_type -> value as defaultValue). So the query returns:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| typeId | absenceId | employeeId | entitlement | defaultValue | totalDuration | 
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|  1     |   null    |    112     |   12        |   20         |       0       |
|  2     |   null    |    112     |   null      |   null       |       0       |
|  3     |   null    |    112     |   null      |   null       |       0       |
|  4     |   null    |    112     |   null      |   null       |       0       |
|  9     |   145     |    112     |   null      |   null       |       1       |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Seems straightforward, but the query I got returns only one row which has a record in `absences` table (the last one).

```
select 
  `t`.`id` as `typeId`,
  `a`.`id` as `absenceId`,
  `a`.`employeeId`, 
  `b`.`entitlement`,
  `t`.`value` as `defaultValue`,
  `a`.`totalDuration` 
from `absence_type` as `t` 
left join `absences` as `a` on `a`.`absenceTypeId` = `t`.`id`
left join `absence_balance` as `b` on `b`.`employeeId` = `a`.`employeeId` 
where (`a`.`employeeId` = 112 or `a`.`employeeId` is null) 
and (`b`.`periodYear` = 2023 or `b`.`periodYear` is null)
and (`a`.`startDate` between '2023-01-01' and '2023-12-31' or `a`.`startDate` is null)
and `t`.`id` in (1,2,3,4,9)
group by `a`.`id`
```

Comment: Put the conditions on the `LEFT JOIN` tables in the `ON` clause rather than `WHERE`, then you don't need all those `OR xxx IS NULL` tests. Then use `IFNULL()` in the `SELECT` list to provide a default value.'

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion from @Barmar here is a revised query, that moves the conditions into the join criteria:

```sql
SELECT
    t.id,
    a.id AS absenceId,
    112 AS employeeId,
    b.entitlement,
    t.value AS defaultValue,
    IFNULL(a.totalDuration, 0) AS totalDuration
FROM absence_type AS t
LEFT JOIN absences AS a ON
    t.id = a.absenceType
    AND a.employeeId = 112
    AND a.startDate BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
LEFT JOIN absence_balance AS b ON
    t.id = b.absenceType
    AND b.employeeId = 112
    AND b.periodYear = 2023
WHERE t.id IN (1,2,3,4,9);
```

When I run this it almost gives the desired result set:

```
+------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| id   | absenceId | employeeId | entitlement | defaultValue | totalDuration |
+------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|    1 |      NULL |        112 |          12 |         NULL |             0 |
|    2 |      NULL |        112 |        NULL |         NULL |             0 |
|    3 |      NULL |        112 |        NULL |           20 |             0 |
|    4 |      NULL |        112 |        NULL |         NULL |             0 |
|    9 |       145 |        112 |        NULL |         NULL |             1 |
+------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

The difference is in `defaultValue` - which I think is rightly shown here against type 3.